# What do following words/phrases mean? (2)

Tags: translation

This is the continuation of [the previous question: "What do following words/phrases mean? (1)"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410337/what-do-following-words-phrases-mean-1?noredirect=1#comment978036_410337).

I'd appreciate any suggestions on what the bolded texts mean.

> We can vouch for the sweeter proportions and prettier detailing
>   because TopGear was invited up to Crewe for a secret audience with the
>   new GT, and **in the metal** it makes a stunning impression. **Those lower,
>   faster haunches are almost 911-ish,** and the **oval lights** come straight
>   from the EXP 10 Speed 6 concept. ...
>
> Inside, wow. The dash has a **party** piece. Bored of the pin-sharp
>   12.3-inch touchscreen? It’ll electrically rotate, exposing a **triplet** of old-school temperature gauges (with yet more digital readouts embedded in them). Short attention span? Then turn the
>   **Toblerone panel** again, and a veneer section turns into view
>
> The **cabin** was designed by Bentley’s chief cabin artiste, and a
>   gentleman with the greatest name in all of motoring: Romulus Rost.
>   Among his past works is the very  rst Audi TT cockpit, which ranks as
>   one of the most enduring, iconic car interiors of the past 25 years.
>   He points out Bentley’s subtle deployment of **real metal** where the
>   customer’s **touchpoints** lie, and tells us he voted for physical
>   buttons rather than Panamera- style touch-sensitive glass to make the
>   Continental more familiar and traditional to use.

---

I understand them to mean the following:

- **in the metal**: in its simplest form (i.e. without any design)
- **Those lower, faster haunches are almost 911-ish**: those motors situated at the lower back of the car are powerful, almost 911
  horsepower.
- **oval lights**: lights at the front and/or back of the car
- **party**: different
- **triplet**: group of
- **Toblerone panel**: not really sure what this means... I understand "Toblrerone" to mean a Swiss chocolate bar brand.
- **cabin**: the interior of the car
- **real metal**: metal or iron, as opposed to the modern touch screen
- **touchpoints**: the points where people's fingers touch the screen

I've first looked them up in the dictionary and the meanings I came up with their meanings with their context in mind.

Thank you.

Comment: "911" refers to the Porsche 911, and a haunch on a car is in the same position as a haunch on a horse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Motoring journalism often uses stylistic elements that you wouldn't find in general journalism to make it seem that writers are speaking to a cognoscenti, those 'in the know'. But some of your difficulty stems from lack of familiarity with set phrases or certain brands. 
I'll do my best to elucidate:

> - in the metal

Is simply a play on ['in the flesh](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_the_flesh)' meaning when you see the thing itself rather than a picture or description of it.

> In person or (of a thing) in its actual state.
>   e.g. *'they decided that they should meet Alexander in the flesh’*

Oxford Online Dictionary

> - Those lower, faster haunches are almost 911-ish:

This simultaneously compares the car to an animal and another car model. I don't know a great deal about cars but assume 'haunches' equate to the area around the rear wheel arch. [image: Porche 911]

> - oval lights

There isn't enough info here to make clear if they mean headlamps or rear light clusters, but whichever, the reference is to their shape:

> Having a rounded and slightly elongated outline or shape like that of an egg.

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/oval)

> - The dash has a **party piece**

What you need to understand here is not 'party' but 'party piece'.

> A poem, song, or trick regularly performed by someone in order to entertain others.

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/party_piece)
By which the writer means the dashboard has a neat or entertaining feature.

> - triplet

means

> A set or succession of three similar things

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/triplet)

In this case a series of three temperature gauges.

> - Toblerone panel

In this case the reference is to the distinctive *shape* of a Toblerone bar, or more accurately it's box. [image: Toblerone box]
The box is a three sided bar, with a cross-section forming an equilateral triangle. So this part of the dash is a section which rotates on its long axis and can present analogue temperature dials, a digital display or a plain veneered face.

> - cabin

As you suppose, the car interior.

> - real metal:- 'subtle deployment of real metal where the customer’s touchpoints lie'

My interpretation of this, which dictionaries don't help with, is that: at the points where people naturally touch parts of the cabin (not touch screens), anything that *looks* like metal will *be* metal, rather than metallic effect plastic. Therefore will feel solid and be the temperature of metal not plastic, giving a feel of quality material and build.

Comment: Thank you Spagirl for your detailed explanation! Really appreciated it!